# Reached Target shutdown

Tags: shutdown, freeze

1 out of 8 times Ubuntu freezes at shutdown. When I click on <kbd>Esc</kbd> I see the log and it gets stuck at `'Reached target shutdown'` but it never shuts down. I read somewhere about it's a bug and tried to follow the step of pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Prnt screen</kbd> and then typing `REISUB` but nothing would happen. I have been facing this problem for a while now. Could someone please guide me through the solution? Thanks!

Comment: I am having that issue /Reached target shutdown) as well since upgrading to 16.04. Which version are you running?

Comment: I'm using 16.04 as well. I was experiencing the same problem in 14.04 but it was much worse in it. What version were you using prior to the upgrade? Did you ever experience it previously?

Comment: For your information: I thought that my machine was frozen but after spending 45minutes or so in the 'Reached target shutdown' state it actually did the shutdown. I have seen this problem only once and this happened after heavy swapping.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the swap is still active when reaching "Target shutdown"; My solution was to force swap deactivation before reboot :

> ```
> swapoff -a
> swapoff /dev/md6
> ```

after that, the reboot went fine for me without any pause.